# Good resident anti-virus without HTTP, POP3 and LAN scanning, Windows

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus

I'm looking for a good, low-footprint anti-virus package which fulfills these criteria:

- Strong detection rates against viruses and rootkits, from a vendor with a good track record for effective anti-virus protection.
- **No scanning of the local network & Internet HTTP, POP3, etc; or at least the ability to permanently disable these modules.** While I fully understand that the Adobe Flash, Adobe PDF and Sun Java are major attack vectors today, I still do not want the antivirus to interfere with my browser and mail.
- Should still be resident in-RAM and actively scan all files opened, any USB/DVD media attached, etc. In other words, not a strictly on-demand scanner like ClamWin.
- Runs on Microsoft Windows 7 64-bit.

I have used ESET NOD32 for years, and generally been happy with it. However, never versions of NOD32 override my choice of protection modules -- after I disable the HTTP & POP3 scanning, NOD32 silently enables them upon reboot.

tl;dr something like NOD32, but which will obey my choices regarding active modules. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You CAN permanently disable those in NOD32; It's just seems a little goofy at first...

The "Email client protection" and "Web access protection" will always autostart (and re-enable themselves) at boot if any of their sub-nodes (specific protocols) are 'enabled'.

So, in the advanced setup tree, instead of just un-checking "Enable mail client antivirus and antispyware protection" box on the "Email client protection" node, select the "POP3, POP3S" node and disable "Enable POP3 protocol checking".

Same goes for the "Web access protection" node.  Instead of disabling it there, select the "HTTP, HTTPS" node and disabling "Enable HTTP checking".

After reboot they will stay disabled.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Security Essentials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Security_Essentials)?